# Sending custom variables to partial - middleman

Tags: html, ruby, erb, partials, middleman

How do I send a custom variable to a partial with a call from the markup.

```
<%= partial (:contentHeader, :title=>"Title Goes here") %>
/*trying to send a variable named title with "Title Goes Here" to the partial*/
```

The partial is  kind of like this:

```
<div class = "contentHeader">
<h2><%=title%></h2>
</div>
```

So the output should turn out to be

```
<div class = "contentHeader">
<h2>Title Goes Here</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `:locals` to send variables to partial,

```
<%= partial(:contentHeader, :locals => { :title => "Title Goes here" }) %>
```